# connect function of redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

i want to start with redux and the connect function. When i use the useSelector hook, everything is fine, so my redux-state works. But with connect and the maptStateToProps function not. The number variable is undefined.

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { incrementNumber } from '../actions/exampleAction'

const Incrementor = ({ number, increment }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text onPress={increment}>{number}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Incrementor)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    number: state.exampleReducer.number,
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    increment: () => dispatch(incrementNumber()),
  }
};
```

Here is the working solution with react Hooks:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { useSelector , useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { incrementNumber } from '../actions/exampleAction'

const Incrementor = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const number = useSelector(state => state.exampleReducer.number)

  return (
    <View>
      <Text onPress={() => {dispatch({type: "INCREMENT"})}}>{number}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({})

export default Incrementor
```

Here is my reducer function:

```
import { INCREMENT } from "../actions/exampleAction";

let initialState = { number: 0 };

export default function reducer (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INCREMENT:
      return {  ...state, number: state.number+1, };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And here the action:

```
export const INCREMENT = "INCREMENT";

export const incrementNumber = () => {
  return {
    type: INCREMENT,
  }
};
```

Here i combine my reducers:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

import exampleReducer from "./exampleReducer"

const reducers = combineReducers({
  exampleReducer,
});

export default reducers;
```

And here is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';


import Incrementor from './src/components/Incrementor';
import reducer from "./src/reducers/index"

let store = createStore(reducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Incrementor />
      </View>
    </Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: The `connect` function is at this point only really needed for compatibility with legacy class components, and there are good chances that you will never see those in a modern React project. We officially recommend to use the hooks wherever possible.
So while it is not bad that you take a look at it, you probably don't need to spend too much time with it. See the Redux Style guide: https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#use-the-react-redux-hooks-api

Comment: Can you please update your question to include the working hooks-based solution? I suspect you aren't selecting the correct state from redux.

Comment: Yes, i added it.

Comment: I see you also edited what you were selecting in `mapStateToProps`, is there still the undefined `number` prop?

Comment: yes its still undefined.

Comment: In the "hooks" version you import `incrementNumber` but don't dispatch it, can you share the `incrementNumber` action creator implementation as well as the reducer function handling it? ***OR*** if you manually dispatch `dispatch({type: "INCREMENT"})` in the class component does it now work?

Comment: i added my reducer and action function. the dispatch is also undefined. At first i only want that number is not undefined.

Comment: I don't see any overt issue so far. How do you combine the reducers and configure the redux store, and provide it to the app?

Comment: i added it to my post. i do it with combineReducer and createStore method.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, check you've imported incrementNumber() from actions, after that you have to use connect function after defining all mapStateToProps & mapDispatchToProps, your code will be like this

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   number: state
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
 increment: () => dispatch(incrementNumber())
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Incrementor)
```

Comment: Other than inlining some code, how is this significantly different than OP's code? Also, your `mapStateToProps` is now incorrect, it isn't returning an object.

Comment: When i put the connect function under the mapStateToProps Function, i got an Error "Objects are not valid as react child (found: object with keys {reducer)"

Comment: I didnt copy your code
Your mistakes i didnt have in my code.

Comment: actually this error ( i got an Error "Objects are not valid as react child (found: object with keys {reducer)" ) has nothing to do with the codes you've shared, check your reducer structure

Comment: But this error i get, when i put the "export default connect..." under the mapStateToProps Function. When the "export default connect..." is above the mapStaetToProps, i didnt get this error.

Comment: the error you have mentioned has been fixed, there is another problem in your reducer structure

Comment: i add my reducer to the post. Do you see any error?